# Quick debugging typescript in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I can quick debug javascript in vscode by creating a file and the saving that file as `.js` and then hitting `F5`.

However if I make the file `.ts` it is showing me dialog:

> Cannot launch program '/Users/noit/Desktop/debugts/index.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.

Is there a way to quick debug typescript? Or do I have to setup a tsconfig.json or something?

Comment: You have to build the .js file, by pressing CMD/CTRL + Shift + B

Comment: Ah thank you,now i get `tsc: command not found` do i have to `npm i -g tsc`?

Comment: you have to install typescript `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Oh thank you so much it works!!